# setSelectionRange works with input fields, but how can I place the cursor at the end of a contenteditable field?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I previously asked why setSelectionRange was't working and the answer was because it only works with input fields. But I would like to try to develop a spreadsheet type page using the contenteditable attribute.

```js
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode === 113) {
    setFocus()
 }
}


function setFocus() {
  element = document.getElementById('test')
  element.focus() // works
    .setSelectionRange(3,3) // Doesn't work
}
```

```html
<div id="test" contenteditable>testing</div>
<p>Click in the Result window and then press F2.</p>
```

How can I place the cursor at the end of the field once the user presses F2?

Comment: You'll have to create a watcher for the event click. Then write an if where if the button is the unicode equivalent of F2 you will have to apply a css property. That's the description of more or less the direction you would have to go in.

Comment: Is there a way to press the End key for the user?

Comment: key simulation has changed a lot over the past few years. the code found on here about how to simulate an enter press works, even though you want a different key; the boilerplate is current.

Comment: Try the answer here. I'm not sure what kind of element you are using. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596481/is-it-possible-to-simulate-key-press-events-programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a good solution for you:

```js
window.onkeydown = function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode === 113) {
    setFocus()
 }
}


function setFocus() {
  element = document.getElementById('test')
  element.focus() // works
  setCaretPosition(element,1); // Also works
}

function setCaretPosition(el, pos) {
   
  el.focus();
  var range = document.createRange();
  var sel = window.getSelection();
  range.setStart(el, pos);
  range.collapse(true);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

```html
<div id="test" contenteditable>testing</div>
<p>Click in the Result window and then press F2.</p>
```